# dynamic printing in crystal report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have a problem and dont know how to do it.
I need print a report on crystal report(or could be anthin else as need to take a print)
where fields are not fixed which all be printed, example:-
EmpID

EmpName

DOB

DOjoining

Account No.

etc

here we need to give user liberty, to choose any or all fields to print, suppose user selects,
EmpName, DOjoining

so it has print just above two side by side.

Hope I am clear with the question.

Comment: any one....please help....i am stuck